# Unable to access a variable from explicit struct (bring up of union) C#

Tags: c#, struct, unions

I am trying to build a C# explicit `struct` from a C `union`. The explicit struct is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct struct_1
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
   public uint[] All32;

   [FieldOffset(0)]
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
   public struct_2[] bits;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct struct_2
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
   public byte[] Var56;
}
```

These are the structs and I am unable to access `All32` which is `uint` after instantiation from `byte` array (intellisense is showing '?') as following

```
Type structureType = typeof(struct_1);

byte[] b = new byte[4];
b[0] = 0xA0;
b[1] = 0x01;
b[2] = 0xF0;
b[3] = 0x00;

if (structureType != null)
{
   try
   {
      GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(b, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      struct_1 intpdObj = (struct_1)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), structureType);
      handle.Free();
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Your empty `catch` block could be suppressing valuable debugging information.

Comment: I'm not having any "?" issue. [However, here is what i got](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5SkXKnwkJhrWUxiY1FlaHNsaTA/edit?usp=sharing) your first field points to the same address as your second one, and finds struct_2 instead of uint (see the "type" column of my picture)

Comment: Can you post the C struct declarations?

Answer (score 1):

OK. It is because you defined an array inside `struct_2` and that is an object, so the memory address will be put inside that location when `PtrToStructure` creates the struct. You can try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct struct_1
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public uint[] All32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public struct_2 bits;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct struct_2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Var56;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But again the same issue. Unable to access All32. Looks like i have to go the way @Chris pointed out below.

Comment: Strangely this works for me without a problem. `Console.WriteLine(intpdObj.All32[0]);`

Comment: Anyway, you choose the best answer :)

Comment: Sorry @Alireza it was working. I checked the intellisense and inferred wrongly. I printed and it was working.

Answer (score 1):

The `MarshalAs` attribute won't change how the data is represented in your .NET class/struct, it will just change the way the data is marshaled when being passed to other code.  The array will still be a reference to an array, and it all turns to hell about there.

You can overlay two arrays of different types using this methods, but there are some serious gotchas involved.  The biggest issue is that the number of elements will be the same for all of the arrays, but the amount of memory allocated for the arrays will be the same.

Take this union for example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ArrayUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] bytes;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int[] ints;
}
```

If I create a new instance of that struct with a 100-byte array, the `ints` array will also claim to have a length of 100:

```
var u = new ArrayUnion { bytes = new byte[100] };
Console.WriteLine(u.ints.Length);
```

Which of course is incorrect.  If I then try to access anything past the first 25 entries in the `ints` array I'll probably get a serious error and crash.

You can of course wrap some of this stuff into private fields and expose appropriate methods.  Just be careful how you actually access the data... because if you get this wrong you *will* break things.

Comment: Whoa, sketchy. Suddenly unsafe code doesn't seem that bad hehe ;)

Comment: @Chris Yeah, there's `unsafe` code and *unsafe* code.  This is the second type :P  On the other hand it's the fastest way to convert a byte array of arbitrary length back into the ints (or doubles, or whatever) that it represents without using `unsafe`.  It's a hack, but it _does_ work if you're careful with it and know the risks.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `All32` an array? What happens if you try something like this?

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1 )]
public unsafe struct struct_1
{
    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public uint All32;

    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public fixed byte bits[4];
}
```

Edit: If you do want `All32` to be an array:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1 )]
public unsafe struct struct_1
{
    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public fixed uint All32[1];

    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public fixed byte bits[4];
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, but it works..! I'd say doing unions and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` in C# is not very far from unsafe code territory anyway.

Comment: Yeah, pretty close.  You _can_ do it, but it's a terrible idea most of the time.  Handy for super-fast conversions in managed 'safe' code though :P

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Looks like this is the way I have to go. None of the other attempts where working.

Comment: Thanks @Corey. If there exist another way without using "unsafe", would make my job easy.

Comment: The hard thing with the other ways is that the arrays are reference types, and overlapping those references is sketchy at best. With `fixed` it's all embedded directly in the struct.